# Optimal method for the decoding a string encoded using the Fibonacci Code

Tags: c++, performance, fibonacci

I have written an encoder and decoder which utilizes the Fibonacci Code.

For my purpose, I was able to write a decoding function, but it is descructive in nature.
I am looking here for the alternatives which are better in performance and do not destroy the input string in the process.

```cpp
struct symbol
{
    string fibCode;
    unsigned char symbol ;
};

/* decompress message from compfile1.txt */
void decompressMsg(const vector<symbol> &CodedSymbols, string s) {
    size_t pos;
    string delim = "11";
    string dcStr;

    vector<string> brokenStr;

    // break down compressed string using delimiter
    while ((pos = s.find(delim)) != std::string::npos) {
        brokenStr.push_back(s.substr(0, pos + delim.length()));
        s.erase(0, pos + delim.length());
    }

    // match broken down parts of compressed string to fib codes
    for (auto &tk : brokenStr) {
        for (auto &sym : CodedSymbols) {
            if (tk == sym.fibCode)
                dcStr += sym.symbol;
        }
    }

    // print decompressed message
    cout << "Decompressed message = " << dcStr << endl;
}
```

Based on the feedback, I have updated the function to avoid erase function. Here is the updated code.

```
/* decompress message from compfile1.txt */
void decompressMsg(const vector<symbol> &CodedSymbols, string s) {
    size_t pos;
    string delim = "11";
    string dcStr;
    size_t processed;
    vector<string> brokenStr;

    // break down compressed string using delimiter
    processed = 0;
    while ((pos = s.find(delim,processed)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        brokenStr.push_back(s.substr(processed, pos + delim.length() - processed));
        processed = pos + delim.length();
    }

    // match broken down parts of compressed string to fib codes
    for (auto &tk : brokenStr) {
        for (auto &sym : CodedSymbols) {
            if (tk == sym.fibCode)
                dcStr += sym.symbol;
        }
    }

    // print decompressed message
    cout << "Decompressed message = " << dcStr << endl;
}
```

Comment: Pick one language. `vector<string>` is C++, but then you're writing `char *fibEncoding` and `new char[]`. Just use `std::string` consistently. Also, your code appears to be incomplete (`fibEncoding` is not called) and the relation between problem and code is also unclear to me.

Comment: I am trying to optimize the decompress function. At the moment, it uses strtok and eats up the input string. The main focus is on the `void decompressMsg(const vector<symbol> &CodedSymbols, string s)` and others are there to fill the gaps or answer questions related to the various data structures used.

Comment: I don't see `strtok` in `decompressMsg` ? `CodedSymbols` is `const` so that's not eaten up, and `s` is passed by value.

Comment: It would be nice if you can add an example of a valid input which is slow in your code (typically with call to `decompressMsg`).

Comment: What is your input, expected output, and actual output?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is `s.erase(0,`.

That needs to copy the trailing part of `s` to the new front. In general, this makes it O(n*n).

Instead, you can create a new variable `size_t processed`, which keeps track of the part of `s` that you have already processed. In `s.find(delim)`, you can then add `processed` as the start position of the search. Obviouly you'll also need to update the `substr`

Additionally, you can then use `std::string_view` for `brokenStr`. There's no need to copy the substrings.